# A couple on a yacht needs medical help but can only get it via radio from an astronaut

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a story I've heard about but never been able to find.
I've been looking for it for a long time, but the search terms I put in (astronaut, yacht, couple, medical help etc) tend to bring me nothing specific. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: More info about the astronaut would be helpful. Is is a normal person in a human-built spacestation around Earth? Or is he in the future and they communicate via some time warp? Is he an alien who visits Earth just to observe, but he feels compelled to help anyway? Is he a he?

Comment: It's just your basic human astronuat, but he's doomed because he's stuck on a path into the sun...or out of the solar system I forget which.